# Magento 2 CE upgrade hangs while update application is running

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have a clean M2 CE install.
When trying to upgrade from 2.02 to 2.04, the update takes forever and seems to hang.

The System Upgrade Status is "Update application is running".

In the Console Log, the last two lines of code are:

```
[2016-04-18 15:08:06 UTC] Starting composer update...
[2016-04-18 15:08:06 UTC] ./composer.json has been updated
```

I don't see a progression bar or anything else that indicates that the update is still being carried out.

Should I just wait longer or should I upgrade in a different way? Or do I need to change settings, e.g. on the server?

Comment: `I'm having the exact same issue. It's been 15+ minutes. Did yours end up working ?`  ask by http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/38828/user1010211

Comment: Make sure you follow the [checklist](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_compman-checklist.html). If so, look in `php.ini` to see if there is a PHP log file. If not, set one up. That might provide the information you need to go farther.

Comment: @ Steve Johnson: Thanks, but I am just a CMS user. I did a new install. I hope I don't need to perform a new install every time I need to do a small update ;-)

Comment: @ Amit Bera: I ended up performing a new install. See the answer below. If you are more familiar with the CLI than I am, you might find a solution there.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up removing the `.maintenance.flag` from **/magento/var** to get access back to my store. the upgrade did not finish. Going back in **"settings / web setup wizard"** brings me back to the same console message.

Update: The solution is to do an upgrade on the command line:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.4 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

You may need to do this as well, if you have a 500 HTTP Error

```
chown -R :apache .
```

Comment: @ user1010211: Thanks for your comment. Since I am not a CLI expert, I was hoping to perform a Magento update without using the command line. One would expect that a CMS update can be performed by a user, not an admin with CL skills. Any other way you know of?

Comment: Perfect, it worked great..

Comment: I get an error:  Problem 1 - The requested package /product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name. Potential causes: - A typo in the package name - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability settin

Answer (score 0):

Magento has addressed the problem and provides a solution in this patch and devdoc: "New Community Edition 2.0.x Patch (MDVA-532) Enables Upgrades to Magento 2.1 – June 22, 2016":

Update 17-11-2017: link to the patch is dead because new Magento versions don't have this specific problem anymore. Which doesn't mean btw that upgrade will never hang anymore.

Comment: Apparently they forgot to add this patch, if it truly works, to v2.2.1. Extensions still don't install!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the suggestion above from user1010211, there is an additionial solution that uses the CLI as well.
When update hangs, I usually kick the cron job from the command line using:

```
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

You might need to use above code several times (sometimes as much as 10 times).
After each time you have used the commands in the CLI, check the last line in the Console Log in the Magento backend System Upgrade Page in order to check whether the commands have had any result.